# SPGridView Sorting, Filtering and Paging

Tags: spgridview, sorting, web-part

I'm currently working on my first SharePoint web part to aggregate information from numerous announcement lists in various sites and allow them to be displayed in one single web part.

I've used two guides but had little success, these are [Powlo's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powlo/archive/2007/02/25/displaying-custom-data-through-sharepoint-lists-using-spgridview-and-spmenufield.aspx) and [Erik Burgers SPGridView series](https://web.archive.org/web/20160307052621/http://reversealchemy.net/2009/05/01/building-a-spgridview-control-part-1-introducing-the-spgridview), I have had more success with Eriks than Powlos guide, but it is still not working as intended.

When attempting to sort I click on the title of the column I wish to sort and [this error](http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/1042/error1j.png) is displayed within the webpage. The drop down is then shown giving the option to sort by asscending and descending, once I click on one of the options I recieve a full page error saying "The Gridview 'grid' first event sorting which wasn't handled.

Second to this I have paging implemented but when I try to use it the web part displays the message "There are no items to show in this view".

Further to that, when using the drop down for Sorting no filtering options appear.

I've included my code below, so if you have any suggestions let me know please.

(Excuse the messy code I've been using it for debugging and generally playing with things to see if they would make it work.)

```
public partial class AggregationWebPartUserControl : UserControl
    {
        SPSite thisSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
        SPWebCollection thisWeb;
        SPListCollection siteLists;
        DataTable dt;
        ObjectDataSource gridDS;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

            thisWeb = thisSite.AllWebs; //thisSite.OpenWeb();
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindToGrid(thisWeb, grid);
            }
        }

        private void BindToGrid(SPWebCollection thisWeb, SPGridView grid)
        {
            //Use a ObjectDataSource to bind to the data table
            gridDS = new ObjectDataSource();
            gridDS.ID = "gridDS";
            //We select the method the data is pulled from
            gridDS.SelectMethod = "SelectData";
            gridDS.TypeName = this.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
            gridDS.ObjectCreating += new ObjectDataSourceObjectEventHandler(gridDS_ObjectCreating);
            this.Controls.Add(gridDS);

            //Set the datasource of the grid to the instance of ObjectDataSource
            grid.DataSourceID = gridDS.ID;
            grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

            //Turns on Paging along with setting the default page size
            grid.AllowPaging = true;
            grid.PageSize = 10;


            //Allows sorting
            grid.AllowSorting = true;

            //Filtering
            grid.AllowFiltering = true;
            //Allows filtering on the Created and ListName columns
            grid.FilterDataFields = ",,ListName";
            grid.FilteredDataSourcePropertyName = "FilterExpression";
            grid.FilteredDataSourcePropertyFormat = "{1} = '{0}'";

            //FIltering and Sorting Event handlers
            grid.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(grid_RowDataBound);
            gridDS.Filtering += new ObjectDataSourceFilteringEventHandler(gridDS_Filtering);
            grid.Sorting += new GridViewSortEventHandler(grid_Sorting);

            this.Controls.Add(grid);

            //Sets up the paging used on the page
            SPGridViewPager pager = new SPGridViewPager();
            pager.ID = "newPager";
            pager.GridViewId = grid.ID;

            this.Controls.Add(pager);
        }

        protected sealed override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            GenerateColumns();
            grid.DataBind();
            base.Render(writer);
        }

        private void GenerateColumns()
        {
            BoundField column = new BoundField();
            column.DataField = "Title";
            column.SortExpression = "Title";
            column.HeaderText = "Title";
            grid.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new BoundField();
            column.DataField = "Created";
            column.SortExpression = "Created";
            column.HeaderText = "Created";
            grid.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new BoundField();
            column.DataField = "ListName";
            column.SortExpression = "ListName";
            column.HeaderText = "ListName";
            grid.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        public DataTable SelectData()
        {
            try
            {
                dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Title");
                dt.Columns.Add("Created");
                dt.Columns.Add("ListName");

                DataRow row;

                foreach (SPWeb web in thisWeb)
                {
                    siteLists = web.Lists;
                    siteLists.ListsForCurrentUser = true;

                    foreach (SPList list in siteLists)
                    {

                        if (list.BaseTemplate.ToString() == "Announcements")
                        {
                            SPListItemCollection listItem = list.Items;

                            foreach (SPListItem item in listItem)
                            {

                                row = dt.Rows.Add();

                                row["Title"] = item["Title"].ToString();
                                //row["Title"] = "<a href=\"" + item.Url + "\">" + item["Title"].ToString() + "</a>";
                                row["Created"] = item["Created"].ToString();
                                row["ListName"] = list.Title;
                                //row["ListName"] = "<a href=\"" + list.DefaultViewUrl + "\">" + list.Title + "</a>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return dt;
            }

            catch (Exception s)
            {
                return dt;
            }
        }

        #region eventhandlers

        private void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender == null || e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                return;
            }

            SPGridView grid = sender as SPGridView;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(grid.FilterFieldName))
            {
                return;
            }

            // Show icon on filtered column
            for (int i = 0; i < grid.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                DataControlField field = grid.Columns[i];

                if (field.SortExpression == grid.FilterFieldName)
                {
                    Image filterIcon = new Image();
                    filterIcon.ImageUrl = "/_layouts/images/filter.gif";
                    filterIcon.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginLeft] = "2px";

                    // If we simply add the image to the header cell it will
                    // be placed in front of the title, which is not how it
                    // looks in standard SharePoint. We fix this by the code 
                    // below.
                    Literal headerText = new Literal();
                    headerText.Text = field.HeaderText;

                    PlaceHolder panel = new PlaceHolder();
                    panel.Controls.Add(headerText);
                    panel.Controls.Add(filterIcon);

                    e.Row.Cells[i].Controls[0].Controls.Add(panel);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //Used to filter data
        private void gridDS_Filtering(object sender, ObjectDataSourceFilteringEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewState["FilterExpression"] = ((ObjectDataSourceView)sender).FilterExpression;
        }

        //Used to sort the data
        private void grid_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ViewState["FilterExpression"] != null)
            {
                gridDS.FilterExpression = (string)ViewState["FilterExpression"];
            }
        }


        protected sealed override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
        {
            base.LoadViewState(savedState);

            if (Context.Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"] != null &&
                 Context.Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"].EndsWith("__ClearFilter__"))
            {
                // Clear FilterExpression
                ViewState.Remove("FilterExpression");
            }
        }

        private void gridDS_ObjectCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
        {
            e.ObjectInstance = this;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: have u solved the issue...

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you on post backs do not create the ObjectDataSource object and configure the SPGridView object. Refactor your code to do this in the CreateChildControls() method that you must override from the base class. Also call grid.DataBind() in the PreRender phase and not in the Render phase.

Here is another useful article on the SPGridView control: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/SPGridviewWebpart.aspx

Answer (score 0):

About your problem with the page indexing, it occurs because you are not implementing any paging logic beyond the fact that you define the paging properties of the gridview.

You would need to add the event:

```
 grid.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(gridOrdenes_PageIndexChanging);
```

The implementation of the event:

```
protected void gridOrdenes_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
             if (ViewState["FilterExpression"] != null)
            {
                gridDS.FilterExpression = (string)ViewState["FilterExpression"];
            }

            grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

        }
```

The following property (or subtitute) defined with the other gridview properties:

```
grid.PagerTemplate=null;
```